# Create texture from byte array in OpenGL, Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to display a byte array in an OpenGL `GLSurfaceView`.

So I have a `GLRenderer`class implementing `Renderer` and a method `onSurfaceCreated`

```java
byte[] data = new byte[512*512];
            for (int i = 0; i < 512*512; i++) {
                data[i] = 100;
            }
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(512*512);
            buffer.put(data);
            buffer.position(0);

            GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 512, 512, 0,
                    GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

But nothing is displayed on the screen. FYI, there is no special code in `onSurfaceChanged` and `onDrawFrame` method.

Comment: You need 4 bytes of data per pixel if you're using unsigned byte RGBA format. Also what do you mean there is no special code in `onDrawFrame`? How do you bind the texture?

Comment: Use the GL_RED color format then, and go back to 1 byte per pixel.

Comment: @pleluron thank you for your response, it worked. Could you post the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format and data size don't match. GL_RGBA takes up 4*sizeof(type) per texel so you need to scale the buffer accordingly. However, if you only want a single channel texture, use GL_RED instead.